# How to make snap notepad-plus-plus to support Chinese text?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, notepad++, snapcraft

In Ubuntu/Linux, we can install notepad-plus-plus by snap. Basically, it works fine, but seems couldn't display Chinese text(garbled).

Sincerely, is there anyone have a workaround to fix it?

Comment: Problem solved by "https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/call-for-testing-notepad-plus-plus/4498/10".

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced a same problem about Korean.
More easier way is here.

1. Find default font for snap notepad-plus-plus.

```
$ gedit ~/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/system.reg

"MS Shell Dlg"="Gulim"
```

2. Copy the font file into snap notepad-plus-plus wine folder. (For me, it was Gulim.ttc)

```
$ cp Gulim.ttc ~/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts/
```

3. Relaunch snap notepad-plus-plus

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install fonts-wqy-zenhei